# Template inheritance with plain PHP

Tags: php

I am building a small MVC app and I'd like to serve webpages that inherit from the base (i.e. parent) template. So, I've created a `View.php` class to initialize templates:

```
<?php

class View {

    protected $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "views/";

    protected $data;

    public function __construct() { $this->data = array(); }

    public function render($view) {
        if ( file_exists($this->path.$view) )
            include $this->path.$view;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) { $this->data[$name] = $value; }

    public function __get($name) { return $this->data[$name]; }
}
```

To load an independent template, I can do the following from `routes.php`:

```
$v = new View();
$v->people = ["josh", "alex", "michel"];
$v->render('welcome.php');
```

and `welcome.php` itself would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php print_r($this->people) ?>
</body>
</html>
```

## Problem

This would work for independent webpages. What I want to do is implement **template inheritance** (just like in Twig or Blade), so that `welcome.php` can inherit from `app.php`. Here is what I am envisioning:

**app.php (parent)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <header>...</header>
    <?php ***include('content')*** ?>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.php (child)**

```
<?php ***extends('app.php')*** ?>

<?php ***block('content')*** ?>
    <h1>You made it to welcome.php!</h1>
<?php ***END block('content')*** ?>
```

#### How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use twig? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: You can't do it in procedural way (not directly) where assignment is paralel with execution. You need to build a composition first and then execute it from top layer to bottom one. The easiest way would be separate `phtml` partials from delegated objects that could be composed. But these partials would not provide knowledge of its parent template, because it would come too late (while they are parsed/executed), so that knowledge need to stay within objects handling them. Template engines translate pseudocode into reverted composition (objects or procedures).

Answer (score 1):

To those interested, I was able to approximate template inheritance using [this tutorial](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). It allows to bind variables both to parent and child templates, but it does not allow to overwrite more than one block in a single child template. So, you can't really have a section for content, styles, and scripts; you can only accomodate content; otherwise, you'd need to include markup from other PHP files. I am guessing this would require including custom tags and parsing them whem, but I didn't find a solution to this online. If anyone comes across a workaround, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

**shortly**: you can not do that just by including php files.

For support that you have to parse templates, build template structure. Find all control blocks and execute statement by statement.

Once you have template structure it will be easy to overwrite any part of template.